# Array with multiple data types

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I want to make array for positions (x, y, z)

It would be something like this:

```
/*Whatever the type*/ array[100] = {(1, 2, 3), (4, 2, 5)....}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot declare a variable name with `void`.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: `int array[100][3]` would have been fine.

Comment: Array with *multiple data types* – you can't store multiple data types in a static array, only a single type. Coordinates are usually represented with integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, making a `struct` makes the program much simplified:

```
struct location {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

int main(void) {
    location array[100];

    // Example initialization of the first index
    array[0].x = 10;
    array[0].y = 20;
    array[0].z = 30;

    // Or, even better...

    array[0] = {10, 20, 30};
    .
    .
}
```

In case you want to manually initialize `x, y, z` of each, then:

```
location array[100] = {{1, 4, 3}, {3, 0, 2}, {}, ...}
```

**Note:** These values are not required, they are just to demonstrate the initialization.

Comment: `typedef struct ...` is useless in C++. `struct {...] location;` is enough...

Comment: Why not follow their required initialization syntax and suggest `location array[100] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 5} /*...*/ };`